# Using a variable declared in asyncfileupload OnUploadedComplete event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have to create a movie database website (similar to Microsoft's MVC tutorial but using regular ASP.NET).

To add a new movie I'm using the AsyncFileUpload control from the AJAX Control Toolkit. The file uploads asynchronously and then the user clicks submit to add all of the movie's information to the DB.

The following is my OnUploadedComplete event:

```
  protected void AjaxImageUpload_OnUploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
            imgfilename = filename;
            AjaxImageUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/MovieThumbs/") + filename);
        }

    }
```

The event fires and the file is saved properly but I want to use the filename string in the event where the data is added to the DB. The variable imgfilename is a string I declared as null on the class level but when the upload event is complete its value keeps reverting to null.

Basically I want to use the value of the filename string in other events.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the filebyte saved in the database?

Comment: Solved it myself, was being stupid (only way you learn). I didn't know about the PostedFile property. Thanks anyways.